# Why SVD is talk about less than QR and LU for sparse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, matrix, svd, eigen

For example the C++ sparse matrix libraries I used -- Eigen and SuiteSparse, they seem not to have any SVD funcitionality for sparse matrix. So just curious, is SVD more difficult than QR/LU for sparse matrix?

Answer (score 13):

The LU factors of a sparse matrix are at least somewhat sparse. The $Q$ matrix in QR can also somewhat preserve sparsity, and is typically used when the matrix is very long and skinny. The SVD of a sparse matrix will almost always have fully dense $U$ and $V$ factors, so it destroys any reason to perform the computations treating the matrix sparsely.

Comment: More importantly in the typical case of the QR factorization you only need to apply $Q^{T}$ to a right hand side vector $b$.  This can be done during the QR factorization process without storing the $Q$ matrix or all of the Householder reflections used in the factorization.  There's no similar trick for the SVD.